# Relative paths in tag file

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

If a tags file contains relative paths, Vim attempts to locate the source file relative to the location where the tag file itself lies, not from the current directory. I.e. the tag file must lie where `ctags -R` was run from.

Any way to get Vim to locate the source file from the PWD, in case I want to keep the same tag file elsewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `set notagrelative` to your .vimrc file.  Quoting from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags):

> 'tagrelative' - Controls how the file names in the tags file are treated. When on, the filenames are relative to the directory where the tags file is present.

Comment: Ha! Can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:set tags=/path/to/your/tagfiles` to load tags files from any directory.

Comment: I tried that even before posting here. If relative paths are present in tag file, Vim seems to locate source files from where the tag file is located, as opposed to $PWD. I.e. if you've `foo/bar.c` in `/path/to/tag` file, Vim tries to open `/path/to/foo/bar.c`.